# Redirect certain requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC3.  We have a single website, but we will spin off some parts of the website to a new website.  So some controllers will be moved to the new website.  We want to redirect users to the new website if they try to access pages that used to be in the main website.

**Current web site structure:**

```
http://www.current.com/A
http://www.current.com/B
http://www.current.com/X
http://www.current.com/Y
```

**New web site structure:**

*Website One*

```
http://www.current.com/A
http://www.current.com/B
```

*Website Two*

```
http://www.new.com/X
http://www.new.com/Y
```

As you can see we are going to move controllers `X` and `Y` to a new website under www.new.com.  Now if a user tries to access `http://www.current.com/X` or `http://www.current.com/Y`, we want to redirect them to `http://www.new.com/X` or `http://www.new.com/Y`.  We will not redirect users who try to access controllers **`A`** and **`B`**.

What is the best way to do this?  I have looked into custom routing but haven't seen any examples that demonstrate the behavior above.  We don't want to do any redirecting through IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I know you say you don't want to do your redirecting through IIS, but what about the IIS Rewrite module that's entirely configurable through your web.config's `system.webServer` element?

I don't have the exact syntax handy, but you could use regex matching for controller's X & Y and redirect the url to the other domain that you wish to use.

Your requirement on IIS is low at this rate, only having to have the module installed and rely on your web.config to configure the rest.

This post could get you on the correct path for domain level rewriting: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one

Answer (score 0):

Routing cannot redirect to you to different domain easily.  However, if you really really do not want to use IIS Rewrite rules (which can be configured your web.config), The easiest method would be to make the controllers on the current site issue a redirect when they are hit.

```
public Controller X{

  public ActionResult Index(){
     return Redirect("http://www.new.com/X");
  }
}
```

You could also use a custom HTTPModule to handle the redirect for you

```
public class RedirectHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
          context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
          HttpContext context = application.Context;

          //check here context.Request for using request object 
          if(context.Request.FilePath.Contains("ControllerPath"))
          {
               //do some extra work here to get the actual complete path
               context.Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://www.new.com/{0}", Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
          }
    }
```

}

You would have to register the HttpModule in your web.config for it to work properly.